# Mysql count same values and group by max

Tags: mysql

I write a report system so users can report any content by choosing some specific reasons.
I have reports table and one of the columns named "reason" it is enum.

I'm trying to list reported posts on moderation page, according to the column (reason) content with highest number in the table.

The reports table:
[Reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8yMM.png)

"violation" is 2. Others are single. So on top of post there should be written "violence".

The posts table:
[Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Vk3.png)

What I try:

```
SELECT * FROM reports r
INNER JOIN posts p
ON r.contentid=p.id
WHERE r.type=:type
AND (SELECT reason, count(*)
AS NUM FROM reports
GROUP BY reason)
GROUP BY p.id
```

I have no any data on the moderation page, help pls.

Comment: your select in the where clause makes no sense, what do you want to achieve and please **don't** post images only text

Comment: Thanks for comment but this is not helpful at all. Also why shouldn't I upload images? I have this permission

Comment: look to test queryies we need text not images please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question also SELECT reason, count(*)... can't be used in the where, so explain in detail why what you wnat to select

Comment: Ok sorry I don't know the rules well, I'll not do again. Im trying to count same values and show the value which is highest number in table. I am newbie about Mysql and I don't know what can I try else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUPING should have all columns that are not in the GROUP BY should be in a [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

But i think you want only want an ORDER BY i9nstead of a GROUP BY

```
SELECT r.*,p.*,NUM 
FROM reports r
INNER JOIN posts p
ON r.contentid=p.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT reason, count(*) 
AS NUM FROM reports
GROUP BY reason) t1
ON t1.reason = r.reason
WHERE r.type=:type 
ORDER BY NUM DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, actually I should use GROUP BY, because I just tried your way and I see same contents as the number of reports for same content on moderation page. Now there's 4 row in reports table, reasons: "spam (1) - inappropriate language (1) - violation (2)".  The reported post is only, but page shows 4 posts.

Comment: that os why you should post a [mre]  feel free to adapt it to your desired outcome, because i don't know that.

Comment: I can't understand, I post two images in the question. It is clear enough but it is okay. You give me an idea, I'll try different things with the code you wrote. Thanks.